# What feeds should our main chat include?

Tags: discussion, chat

Our [main chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12036/aviation) has an option to include RSS / Atom feeds and display them as either:

- **Message feeds**: New items from these feeds will be posted into the room like regular chat messages.
- **Ticker feeds**: New items from these feeds will be shown via a slide-down ticker overlay that periodically appears at the top of the room, and will not be persisted.

These feeds can be managed by any of the Stack Exchange moderators or individual room owners and they can provide useful information to most of its members and keep conversations alive (or provide for new topics to chat about). So they are sort of important, but too many can also clutter the chat room or be even seen as spammy or otherwise unwanted. So I'm posting this question here for all of you to provide suggestions that we can vote on.

Please add new suggestions in the following format:

```
##Title

URL to the RSS / Atom feed

Short description

---

[Optional] Example feed item, either as formatted text or an image
```

With one suggestion per answer, and you can of course add multiple answers. Please don't duplicate suggestions! Sufficiently upvoted* suggestions will be added to our chat room and indicated as such by editing their title, attaching "Added" to it. If you would like to suggest what kind of feeds they should be added to (ticker or message feeds), please do so in their *Short description*.

***Suggestions posted below with a minimum of three votes that reach an equal or greater than [median](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median) vote score out of all suggested feeds  will be included in our chatrooms's list of feeds.**

---

I have already added two most common feeds to our [main chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12036/aviation):

- [**Recent Questions - Aviation Meta Stack Exchange**](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/feeds) as a Message Feed and
- [**Recent Questions - Aviation Stack Exchange**](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/feeds) as a Ticker Feed

Meta questions are less frequent and should concern anyone in the Aviation main chat room, so I've added them to be included as normal chat messages, while the new questions of the Aviation main site could be too frequent and might not be interesting to all in the room, so I've added them as a *ticker feed* that doesn't clutter the chat room's conversation space. This can of course be later changed, or removed altogether.

Comment: I've gone ahead and thrown a few in there already because OH BOY is our chat dead -- links below, if y'all hate 'em downvote 'em and I'll make 'em go away :-)

Answer (score 3):

### StackExchange Blog

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/feed/

One of *the usual suspects* in most Stack Exchange chat room feeds is the [Stack Exchange Blog](https://stackexchange.com/blogs). They aren't too frequent, but relevant to any *Stacker* and they're sometimes even interesting. :P

**Example feed**:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

### AviationWeek.com Business Aviation Channel

http://www.aviationweek.com/myAviationweek.aspx?rss=true&key=busav

[AviationWeek.com Business Aviation](http://www.aviationweek.com/BusinessAviation.aspx) news, analysis, blogs and product spotlight RSS feed. Frequency of new feed items on average seems to be roughly one per day.

Answer (score 2):

### AviationWeek.com Commercial Aviation Channel

http://www.aviationweek.com/myAviationweek.aspx?rss=true&key=comm

[AviationWeek.com Commercial Aviation](http://www.aviationweek.com/CommercialAviationChannel.aspx) news, analysis, blogs and product spotlight RSS feed. Frequency of new feed items on average seems to be roughly two per day.

Answer (score 2):

## [AvWeb Insider Blog Postings](http://www.avweb.com/blogs/insider/) ([RSS](http://www.avweb.com/blogs/insider/?zkDo=showRSS))

These can be hit or miss, but many of them are interesting and the volume is pretty low at a few a week (maybe a bit more in the USA aviation show season).

Answer (score 2):

Courtesy of TidalWave converting it into a feed:

## [NASA ASRS Callback](http://asrs.arc.nasa.gov/publications/callback.html) ([RSS](http://www.feed43.com/5764684453773775.xml))

Cribbed directly from NASA's description: *CALLBACK* is a monthly safety newsletter, which includes de-identified ASRS report excerpts with supporting commentary in a popular “lessons learned” format. In addition, *CALLBACK* may contain features on ASRS research studies and related aviation safety information.

This is a pretty low volume feed (monthly). Though it's assembled from (US) ASRS reports the analysis and discussions in the monthly newsletter are applicable no matter where/what you fly.

Answer (score 1):

## [Uncontrolled Airspace episodes](http://uncontrolledairspace.com) ([RSS](http://feeds.feedburner.com/uncontrolledairspace))

Love 'em, hate 'em, they're still turning out episodes ***how*** many years later?!
Not weekly (or even monthly) anymore, but when they come out I always find them worth listening to.

Answer (score 1):

## [FAASafety's Weekly tips/lessons](http://www.faasafety.gov/gslac/ALC/lib_categoryview.aspx?categoryId=21) ([RSS](https://www.faasafety.gov/RSS/LessonsRSS.aspx))

This one seems to have gone defunct, which is a shame - Hopefully it comes back (or maybe one of you fine folks has an updated RSS feed for it!)
This is a relatively low-volume set of posts of pretty decent quality, if a bit US-centric.

Answer (score 0):

### XKCD

http://xkcd.com/rss.xml

[XKCD](http://xkcd.com/) comics display as *oneboxed* images in Stack Exchange chats, meaning they have been thought of in advance and Stack Exchange chat software custom parses them for display purposes. In this case, they are displayed at their full width, or as much as it would fit in the chat window, instead of resized to maximum width for user added images that are much narrower. New XKCD images are usually posted daily, sometimes less frequently, but they certainly won't cutter the chat space.

**Example feed**:

[image]